# Is it possible to give a 3rd party access to my google analytics data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I host my own trading site but use a 3rd party for backend processing - Inventory / Order Management.  The 3rd party would like to access my google analytics data to allow them to create some reports.  I have looked at the GA terms of service but cannot find anything specifically relating to this.  The question is - is this allowed and if so what is the best way of achieving this to minimise the impact of future change at the GA end?

Comment: Google Analytics API, with a service account.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the administrator tab you can add new users and manage their privileges. I foresee no reason why tha analytics team may change that in the future so I expect it to be an stable feature of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Your Google Analytics account is yours to give access to as you wish, so there is no trouble there.

For your own sake, it would probably be best if you set up a View just for your 3rd party to view, and give them Read/Analyse level access to that.  That will allow them to use the GA API and login to see the data specific to them, but won't let them be able to add new users or change your other settings.

[A reference on creating Views is here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en)